# Julia: empty vector of strings

Tags: string, vector, julia

I'd like to initialize an empty vector and then add strings to it. However, using `x=[]` creates an empty array of type Any. I've read that specifying types improves performance.

I tried `x = Vector{String}` but other functions (`append`, `join` and `push`) don't work as expected.

Is it possible to creates an empty array of strings to further append strings to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

```
vs = String[]
```

or

```
vs = Vector{String}()
```